# How does a loop on range function with 0 as input works?

Tags: python, range

```py
def power(num, x=1):
    result = 1
    for i in range(x):
        result = result * num
    return result
```

I can't understand how `power` outputs `1` in case the exponent `x` is zero (e.g., `power(2, 0)`).

In other words, how does the loop with `range(0)` works?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first understand what `range` actually does. `range`, in its most basic version, takes a single integer as its parameter (in your case, `x`). It gives a list of integers (in Python 2) as the output (`list` in English is pretty much the same as `list` in python, but I'm not going into details here). The list contains numbers starting from 0 to the parameter, 0 included and the parameter excluded.

So, `range(5)` gives `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Now, your loop effectively becomes:

```
for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., x]:
```

When `x` is 0, then the list can't include 0 either. So you get the following:

```
for i in []
```

Since there are no values `i` can take, the loop doesn't run!

Since you define `result = 1` before the loop, `return result` simply spits out the same value if the loop isn't executed.

In Python 3, the `range()` function gives a `generator` object, similar to the `xrange()` function in Python 2.

Comment: `range` only returns a list in Python 2...

Comment: I don't think adding generators here would help. But I'll rephrase my answer.

Comment: So you think giving wrong information does help?

Answer (score 0):

for the input `power(2,0)` you are overriding the default value of x to 0.

now, inside a function, you have defined `result = 1` as the initial value.

as you are moving in next instruction ie `for i in range(x)`, and `x=0` so this function will return an object with sequence start (inclusive) from 0 to end(exclusive) 0 with an increment (step) of 1, ie it create a empty result (`list(range(0)) = []`.

so as you iterate over it, it will exit the for loop and no operation on `result` variable will occur. so `result` keeps its the default value and you got 1 as return results when you call `power(2,0)`.